# Mysql query and foreach query with double items

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-2

I am just grabbing user data from a few tables but users have the option of adding more than one skill or exp.

```
$query_str = "SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*, e.* FROM edu a
              JOIN exp b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
              JOIN user_profiles c ON a.user_id=c.user_id
              JOIN skills d ON a.user_id=d.user_id
              JOIN comp e ON a.user_id=e.user_id
              WHERE a.user_id = ?";

$query = $this->db->query($query_str, $end_user);
            if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                    foreach($query->result_array() as $stuff) {
                            $data[] = $stuff;
                    }
                    return $data;
                    } else {
            return false;
                    }
```

Everything is fine until I try to display the data. If a user has two exp, everything else is showing up twice. I m not sure how to write this. Would it be easier to do separate them? One query for each item?

```
public function get_education()
    {
           $one_edu = $this->test_model->one_edu($end_user);
            if ($one_edu != false)
            {
                    foreach($one_edu as $edas) {
                            $one_edu_html .='<p>'.$edas['objective'].'</p>';
                    }

                    foreach($one_edu as $exp) {
                            $one_edu_html .= '<p>'.$exp['exp_title'].'</p>';

                    }

                    foreach($one_edu as $educ) {
                            $one_edu_html .= '<p>'.$educ['edu_title'].'</p>';
                    }

                    $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $one_edu_html);
                    echo json_encode($result);
                    exit();
            }else{
                    $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => '');
                    echo json_encode($result);
                    exit();
            }
    }
```

Now it s returning something like this:

```
Objective
Exp title1
Exp title2
Edu title
Edu title <- Extra
```

Using codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for this is because you haven't grouped your rows. Add a grouper, like   `GROUP BY a.id` at the end

---

#### Update

The rows are duplicating because they are different, you can group the field on a single rows, using `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.education, GROUP_CONCAT(a.edu_title SEPARATOR ",") "Edu_Title", GROUP_CONCAT(b.exp_title SEPARATOR ",") "Experience Title" ,b.experience, c.objective, d.skill, e.comp FROM edu a
JOIN exp b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
JOIN user_profiles c ON a.user_id=c.user_id
JOIN skills d ON a.user_id=d.user_id
JOIN comp e ON a.user_id=e.user_id
WHERE a.user_id = 243;
```

#### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d822/7)

Comment: hmm, I guess leaving the search as is and simply adding group by might work... would it automatically create new fields (for multiple value field) or would you still have to tell it to concat them (or other group function)?

Comment: @craniumonempty You need to group where ever its necessary and possibility of redundant fields to arrive.

Comment: GROUP BY doesn't work. It doesn't show multiple fields where it's suppose to.

Comment: @ciprian, Can you create a schema of your database in sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: But, the two row that are coming have different education, what are trying to get here

Comment: Yes, users can add multiple educations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9825/discussion-between-ciprian-and-starx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure exactly how to do it, but you can try a few things. You can set up two distinct subqueries that create extra fields, but that might create unnecessary fields for you. The other thing is to concat results from the other tables and use that. You could also just order them and check for duplicated with php. Either way, group_concat is probably what you are looking for.

I'm unsure of the structure and what you need, but assuming you need 2 fields from skills and 1 from exp:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*, e.*
    FROM edu a,
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s.F1) as d_f1, GROUP_CONCAT(s.F2) as d_f2
       FROM skills s
       WHERE a.user_id=s.user_id
       GROUP BY s.user_id) d,
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.F1) as e_f1
       FROM exp t
       WHERE a.user_id=t.user_id
       GROUP BY t.user_id) e
    JOIN user_profiles b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
    JOIN comp c ON a.user_id=c.user_id
    WHERE a.user_id = ?
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Sorry that I can't test that to see if it works, but you can adjust the separator if you need to and other things. I'm unsure how it will react if there are no matching records, but I assume it will simply return a null or empty string, but you might have to check.

... they might have to go up into the `select` rather than the `from`, but I'm unsure. You'll have to play around with it and see what works and what is faster.

EDIT: I got to test online ( http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/ ), this should work (assuming I didn't screw up something in syntax):

```
SELECT *
    FROM edu a
    JOIN user_profiles b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
    JOIN comp c ON a.user_id=c.user_id
    JOIN (SELECT s.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(s.F1) as d_f1, GROUP_CONCAT(s.F2) as d_f2
       FROM skills s
       GROUP BY s.user_id) d ON a.user_id = d.user_id
    JOIN (SELECT t.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.F1) as e_f1
       FROM exp t
       GROUP BY t.user_id) e ON a.user_id = e.user_id
    WHERE a.user_id = ?
```

That should be faster if you have to do a lot (or basically remove the `where` condition), because I think the subqueries create temp tables and only run once.

.. If you only query one row at a time, then simply stick the conditions back on the subqueries.

Comment: @ciprian you might need to put the userid in the subquery and join on it or something (but make sure you still group by the id) rather than select for it. That might speed things up (I think), because it may only have to do one subquery.

Comment: Hi. Not sure what you mean by "put the userid in the subquery and join on it or something". The query still returns duplicates. I ll keep working on this. Thank you.